# Record deletion by selecting checkbox works fine on first page of Jquery datatables but not in second page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, datatables

I am new to jquery datatables ,I tried may solution given in the stackoverflow but nothing works for me 
So please suggest me what should i to according to my code(easy and simple solution with explanation).

Problem statement-
i implemented checkbox to delete the multiple records of table,
Jquery Datatable works fine on first page, when i click the check all checkbox on first page it checks all the check box of that page and delete the record  but if i am in second page and click check all checkbox then it return to first page, also it will not delete the record if i select the records of two different pages

```js
< script >




  //Delete conformation message
  /***************************/



  //SelectAll checkBox
  /****************************/
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#testtable').dataTable();




    $('#checkall').click(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        $('.delete_checkbox').each(function() {
          this.checked = true;
          $(this).closest('tr').addClass('removeRow');
        });
      } else {
        $('.delete_checkbox').each(function() {
          this.checked = false;
          $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('removeRow');
        });
      }
    });
    /********************************/


    //Select indivisual checkBox
    /*******************************/
    $('.delete_checkbox').click(function() {

      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('removeRow');
      } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('removeRow');
      }
    });
    /*******************************/


    //Deletion of Data
    /***********************************/
    $('#delete_all').click(function() {
      var checkbox = $('.delete_checkbox:checked').prop('checked', this.checked);;
      if (checkbox.length > 0) {
        var result = confirm("Are you sure");
        if (result == true) {
          var checkbox_valu = [];
          $(checkbox).each(function() {
            checkbox_valu.push($(this).val());
          });

          $.ajax({
            url: "delete.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
              checkbox_id: checkbox_valu
            },
            success: function() {
              $('.removeRow').fadeOut(1500);
              location.reload(true)

            }
          });
        } else {
          return false;
        }


      } else {
        alert("Select atleast one records");
      }
    });
    /******************************************/









  });


<
/script>
```

```css
<style>.removeRow {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

</style>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Delete Multiple Records using PHP Ajax with Animated Effect</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">




</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br />
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <h3 align="center">Delete Multiple Records using PHP Ajax with Animated Effect</h3><br />
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="testtable" class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th width="10%">
                <form method="post" action="">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" autocomplete="off" />
                  <button type="button" id="delete_all" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button>
                </form>

              </th>
              <th width="20%">Name</th>
              <th width="38%">Address</th>
              <th width="7%">Gender</th>
              <th width="25%">Designation</th>
              <th width="5%">Age</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <?php
                        foreach($result as $row)
                        {
                            echo '
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" class="delete_checkbox" value="'.$row["id"].'" />
                                </td>
                                <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["address"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["gender"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["designation"].'</td>
                                <td>'.$row["age"].'</td>
                            </tr>
                            ';
                        }
                        ?>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is reloading because your table is inside a form element, and because your action does not have a target the page will just submit to itself. Try

```
$('#buttonId').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

to stop the form submitting the page since you are handling it in JavaScript.

Your function to delete rows does not work on multiple pages because the elements on the other [DataTables] pages do not exist in the DOM. When you click page 2 or whatever, DataTables will redraw the table element to show the new values and the old values are hidden. Paging is just a limit of so many results and DataTables is smart enough to throw that into paging.

Comment: Above code is not working, i use this code below id=checkall in javascript file

Comment: Marks thanks for above answer ,is there is any way to the to delete hidden checkbox in Jquery datatables,How i delete the checked checkbox of previous pages which are not visible??